# How do I change Closure Compiler compile options not exported to command line?

Tags: google-closure-compiler

I found that some options in CompilerOption are not exported to the command line.

For example, `alias all strings` is available in the Closure Compiler's Java API CompilerOption but I have no idea how set this in the command line.

I know I can create a new java class, like:

```
Compiler c = new Compiler();
ComppilerOptions opt = new ComppilerOptions();
opt.setAliasAllString(true);

c.compile(.....);
```

However I have to handle the command line args myself.

Any simple idea?

============================

In order to try the `alias all string` option, I write a simple command line application based on compiler.jar.

However I found that, the result I got when open the `alias all string` is not what I expected.

For example:

```
a["prototype"]["say"]=function(){
  var a="something string";
}
```

Given the above code, the `something string` will be replaced by a variable like this:

```
var xx="something string";

....
var a=xx;
....
```

This is fine, but how about the string "say"? How does the closure compiler know this should be aliased(replace it use variable) or exported(export this method)?

This is the compiled code now:

```
a.prototype.say=function(){....}
```

It seems that it export it.

While I want this:

```
var a="prototype",b="say",c="something string";

xx[a][b]=function(){.....}
```

In fact, this is the google_map-like compilation.

Is this possible?

Comment: This is really two questions and you should split it into two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all options are available from the command line - this includes aliasAllStrings. For some of them you have the following options:

1. Build a custom version of the compiler
2. Use the [Java API](http://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/wiki/FAQ#How_do_I_call_Closure_Compiler_from_the_Java_API?) ([see example](http://blog.bolinfest.com/2009/11/calling-closure-compiler-from-java.html)).
3. Use [plovr](http://plovr.com/)

Getting the same level of compression and obfuscation as the Maps API requires code written specifically for the compiler. When properly written, you'll see property and namespace collapsing, prototype aliasing and a whole host of others. For an example of the style of code that will optimize that way, take a look at the [Closure Library](https://developers.google.com/closure/library/).

Comment: There isn't much on the Java API. I'll update the answer with what links there are.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In fact I have write simple command line application to enable the options in the CompileOption,however I can not know which property will work. I have tried `aliasAllStrings`,`aliasExtern.` and etc. So I think  maybe what I expect can not directly implement by the api itself,so I wonder if you can give me some suggestion to do the `code written specifically` work?

Comment: I think you'll want to look at the Alias Externals pass. That pass will alias things similar (though not exactly) how you specify. It aliases things like `var x = MyObj.prototype; x.y = function() {};`. However it will only create an alias if a specific property is used enough to warrent the extra code size created by the alias.

Answer (score 1):

Modifying http://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/source/browse/trunk/src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/CompilationLevel.java?r=706 is usually easy enough if you just want to play with something.

Comment: Hi,John,I update my post,can you spare some time to have a check?

Answer (score 0):

[Plovr](http://plovr.com/) (a Closure build tool) provides an option called [`experimental-compiler-options`](http://plovr.com/options.html#experimental-compiler-options), which is documented as follows:

> The Closure Compiler contains many options that are only available programmatically in Java. Many of these options are experimental or not finalized, so they may not be a permanent part of the API. Nevertheless, many of them will be useful to you today, so plovr attempts to expose these the experimental-compiler-options option. Under the hood, it uses reflection in Java, so it is fairly hacky, but in practice, ***it is a convenient way to experiment with Closure Compiler options without writing Java code.***